# Plot Equations using Javascript (or anything client side)

Tags: java, javascript, math, plot

Is there any library which I can use to plot mathematical equations? (Preferably using javascript, could me in Java also; or anything clientside)

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at Flot? http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Answer (score 1):

How about [JMathsTool](http://jmathtools.berlios.de/doku.php)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some pages that use http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/ and they look pretty good for Cartesian coordinates. It's also simple to use and works on most browsers.