# Hardcore mathematic and 3d shapes using canvas and javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, wolfram-mathematica

I have an old friend who is a mathematician. He has his own math to compress his formulas, which are incredibly beautiful.

He works in a program called Mathematica, which transforms the formulas for 3D-shapes.

I wonder if it is possible to obtain these figures using Canvas and JavaScript? See attached formula and figure.

I know little of this myself. But I would be delighted if some one could show me an example.

[image: formula]

[image: 3D-shape]

Comment: So what is your question? Are you trying to create a picture or a 3D model?

Comment: I want to put in the formula above in javascript some how and recive the image. I want to know if this is possible and if so I would like to learn how to do it. A 3D-model would be really nice, but a image would be cool to. Is it possible to understand what I mean?

Comment: Try to google for "math formula visualization javascript library", or something along those lines. If that doesn't turn up anything useful... yes, you *can* write something like this yourself, but it's not going to be trivial.

Comment: Thanks deceze, will try to find something. Tough I have problem writing this formula in javascript. Please help if you know how to write the formula with javascript.

Comment: Why not just do it in Mathematica and save the result as a [Computable Document Format](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/compare-cdf/features-of-cdf-documents.html) for embedding in a web page? It can render the 3D graphics in a fully interactive way.

Answer (score 5):

Since you mention Mathematica I'll use it to provide a few more examples for various values of t. I can't help you with canvas though.

This is the Mathematica code:

```
With[{a = 3, t = 0.7}, 
 RegionPlot3D[
  10^-(t x + y)^10 + 10^-(-t x + y)^10 + 10^-(t y + z)^10 + 
    10^-(-t y + z)^10 + 10^-(t z + x)^10 + 10^-(-t z + x)^10 > 
   5/2, {x, -a, a}, {y, -a, a}, {z, -a, a}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   Boxed -> False, Axes -> None
 ]]
```

t=0.2

[image: Mathematica graphics]

t=0.4

[image: Mathematica graphics]

t=0.7

[image: Mathematica graphics]

t=1

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd C. de Vries, Not shore I understand what this is. Is this the formula written in javascript?

Comment: No, as I wrote above this is the Mathematica code. Your equations did include a parameter t. I show some outputs for various values of t, so that others at least know what to expect (and, of course, to show off Mathematica)

Answer (score 4):

It's definitely possible.  You can take a look at the [javascript-surface-plot](http://code.google.com/p/javascript-surface-plot/) library and the working example at http://www.grvisualisation.50webs.com/javascript_surface_plot.html.  It produces a 3D model from a mathematical formula that can be panned and rotated as desired.

If you look at the code for the example, there is a setup function that you would need to update to whatever formula you wanted.  Just need to convert your math formula into javascript.

I'm not sure what you want to do with these models once you have one, but this library seems to fit your requirements. Doing a search for `html canvas 3d plot` brought up additional libraries as well.

Comment: Thanks Bill, looks very interesting! My friend just want to share his shapes with the world (he is writing scientific articles).

Comment: @user1087110 If all you need is putting 3D graphics made using Mathematica online, your best bet is http://www.vis.uni-stuttgart.de/~kraus/LiveGraphics3D/ for Mathematica <= 5.2 or http://www.javaview.de/ for all other versions.

Answer (score 2):

I would think [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) would be ideal for this. It's graphics-accelerated in the newest browsers and can render in full 3D.

Perhaps there are libraries out there that can render from functions out of the box, but it's a new technology so you may have to write much of it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You are really asking two questions:

1. Are there any 3D canvas libraries: **YES** [K3D](http://kevs3d.co.uk/dev/canvask3d/k3d_test.html)
2. Are there math libraries for javascript: **YES** [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397227/plot-equations-using-javascript-or-anything-client-side)

If you are doing hard core math equations (which it looks like you are), you're better off doing it in something like MatLab/Maple and dumping it in a file then using a canvas 2D library to render the image. I have a lot of 3D data and I do just that. I run a Python script which calculates the points then appends it to an html file (rememer, web pages can't read data from file, so you have to include the data as a part of your html file). Then I load the html file and display generate the image using [EaselJS](http://easeljs.com/)

Comment: Thanks puk, will check it out! Do you mean that equations like this are to heavy for a browser to calculate?

Comment: @user1087110 no I did not mean that, although they **might** be too heavy for your browser. I can't say because I don't know the complexity involved in mapping 3D functions. What I do know is that something like MatLab will be orders of magnitude more efficient.

Comment: @user1087110 If your friend wants to 'share his shapes with the world' there are easier ways. A simple `gif` image will do. If he wants to let people rotate/translate/skew it, then all he needs to do is provide the points defining the shape. Only if he wants people to actually change the shape is this approach necessary

Comment: Hi @user1087110, the formula provides the x, y and z points for the figure :)

Comment: @user1087110 I realize that, but you don't need to implement an entire math library to show the result of rendering that formula. Just use MatLab/Maple to generate a few rotated pictures then put it in a gif.